# Passar valores de um JSON para o html via Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json

Estou tentando pegar os dados do JSON do twitch e manipulá-los no html, no caso eu queria montar uma lista simples com os canais online, usando o alert ele mostra os canais porém pensei em imprimir a lista em um ul,li sem precisar mexer no html. Alguém pode me indicar um caminho pra isso?

```
$.ajax({
 type : "GET",
 dataType : "jsonp",
 url : "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?limit=25&offset=25",
 success: function(data){
   for(i=0;i<data.streams.length;i++){
   //alert(data.streams[i]._links.self);
   }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acredito que por "sem mexer no html" você queira dizer colocar o conteúdo na página via javascript, certo?

```
// transforme a lista no que você precisa (lista de li):
var listaDeLi = data.streams.map(function(elemento) {
    return "<li>" + elemento._links.self + "</li>";
});

// coloque o conteúdo gerado em algum lugar
$('#content').append("<ul>" + listaDeLi.join('') + "</ul>");
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qo6dcyt3/1/

Comment: só pra complementar, @Juliano, se eu quisesse criar uma condição baseada em um valor que está no json, tu usaria um if mesmo?

Comment: Depende do que for verificar, mas o if é uma possibilidade. Se for para tirar alguns elementos da lista dependendo da condição, aí eu usaria um filter.