# Exibir no arquivo HTML o arquivo json apenas com jquery ou javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Olá, estou penando para solucionar meu problema.
É o seguinte:
eu tenho uma pagina HTML e um arquivo .json
eu preciso trazer esse arquivo json nessa minha página html usando jquery ou javascript
Eu queria muito pedir pra me passarem exemplos de como faço esse processo passo a passo e se possivel considerando que o json com array e sem array.
Procurei muito na internet mas nenhum conseguiu resolver meu problema, estou com dificuldades tambem com artigos em ingles.

EXEMPLO DO JSON:

```
[{"id": 1, "tipo": "tv", "nome": "Fácil", "descricao": "Lorem ipsum ", "exibir": 1, "ordem": 1, "adesao": 100, "taxaInstalacao": 5, "canais": 7, "listaCanais": [ { "categoria": "Abertos", "descricao": "Canal aberto de variedades abrangente voltado para toda \u00e0 fam\u00edlia.", "id": 465, "imagem": "netcombo.com.br/cs/Satellit";, "nome": "Record"}, "preco":9, "preco2:30},]
```

Comment: EXEMPLO DO JSON: [{"id": 1,
        "tipo": "tv",
        "nome": "Fácil",
        "descricao": "Lorem ipsum ",
        "exibir": 1,
        "ordem": 1,
        "adesao": 100,
        "taxaInstalacao": 5,
        "canais": 7,
        "listaCanais": [
            {
                "categoria": "Abertos",
                "descricao": "Canal aberto de variedades abrangente voltado para toda \u00e0 fam\u00edlia.",
                "id": 465,
                "imagem": "http://www.netcombo.com.br/cs/Satellit",
                "nome": "Record"}, "preco":9, "preco2:30},]

Comment: Passar valores de um JSON para o html via Jquery 
 http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46010/passar-valores-de-um-json-para-o-html-via-jquery?rq=1

Comment: Seu json tá com erro tmb: `"imagem": "netcombo.com.br/cs/Satellit";,` esse ; tem q apagar e: `"preco2:30` tem que fechar as aspas duplas : `"preco2":30`